# How to use ssl client certificates on safari and IOS9

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, ios9, mobile-safari, client-certificates

I provide a web content that requires SSL client certificate authentication.
For this reason users need to install a p12 file in order to see our website content using any browser (desktop or mobile).

This worked like a charm on all platforms, ios (up to vers. 9) included.

Since the last ios upgrade (vers. 9) ipads and iphones can't import anymore our p12 client certificates or our self-signed server CA file and for this reason users can't even surf my protected web area.

I wonder how I can distribute a self-signed certificate to my users in order to allow them use my web service?